# Zurb foundation drop down menu not works

Tags: html, css, ember.js, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I am starting to learn ember and try to incorporate some navigation bar using *zurb foundation* framework. I have a problem with dropdown menu. Check [this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/zJviXNHi6wdZdi16yvi3)

```
 <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
       <h1><a href="#">Home</a></h1>
    </li>
    <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
 </ul>

 <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="left">
       <li class="has-dropdown">
          {{#linkTo "about"}}About{{/linkTo}}
          <ul class="vertical dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
             <li click>{{#linkTo "about.team"}}Team{{/linkTo}}</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li click>{{#linkTo "about.team"}}About/Team again{{/linkTo}}</li>
       <li>{{#linkTo "contact"}}Contact{{/linkTo}}</li>
    </ul>

 </section>
```

I can not achive to trigger route when clicking on About/Team. When clicking on "About/Team again" then route works.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Is `<li click>` a Foundation thing?

Comment: I believe this is happening because when you click the `team` sub-menu, it's triggering the `about` link-to, and transitioning there instead. Also, can I ask why you're using such an old Ember version?

Comment: "click" was a mistake. Regarding to ember version I am going with some tutorial and want to eliminate risk of some big api change.